# Using Python to clear all the cell values in google sheet before adding data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Google Spreadsheet which I'm populating with values using a python script and the SQL query. I need to run the script every one hour, I'd like the script to first clear all the data from the rows before populating it, that way I have a fresh set of data every time I run the script.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for seems to be: [`gspread.Worksheet.clear()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=clear#gspread.models.Worksheet.clear)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `gspread` module, you may want to [delete](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#deleting-a-worksheet) your sheet and re-[create](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#creating-a-worksheet) it every times.

Comment: I want to use the same sheet but want to clear the data and populate new data.

Answer (score 0):

It is old, but that was one of my first hit with google.
So in case it helps someone.
I sorted out with the help of [this example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear):

Using the name of the sheet  in place of the range ("Sheet1" for instance), to clear the whole sheet:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

   def clear_gsheet_range(self,
                           sheet_name: str,
                           sheet_range: Optional[str] = None,
                           ) -> Union[str, None]:
        """Returns the number of cells updated"""
        # https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear


        # The ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
        if sheet_range is None:
            sheet_range_addresses = f"{sheet_name}"
        else:
            sheet_range_addresses = f"{sheet_name}!{sheet_range}"

        try:
            service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=self.authorized_creds)
            clear_values_request_body = {
                # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
            }

            request = service.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_id,
                                                            range=sheet_range_addresses,
                                                            body=clear_values_request_body)
            response = request.execute()

        except HttpError as error:
            print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
            return None

        return response.get("clearedRange")
```

with usage:

```
    my_result = gsheet.clear_gsheet_range(sheet_name="Sheet1",
                                          sheet_range=None,
                                          )
```

It is part of a class so you need to adapt the code for spreadsheet_id/credentials but hopefully that helps or can share the github if need.